# Latex and Thai language

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, memoir, fncychap

I try to use Latex with Thai language.
I found a few problems.

1. `\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}`does not completely support Thai font. (TH Sarabun New is an opentype font)
2. `\bibliography{bib}` do not support Thai font.

There is something wrong with my preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}

% Page Setup
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.81cm}{2.54cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Header & Footer Setup
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth}
\makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}

% Header
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\itshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
% Footer
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}

\makeatletter
% Text at Header
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{    %
\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
\makeatother

%%% Chapter Page
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

% Add Package
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
\usepackage{breqn}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}     %********************

% Font Setup
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1.35}
\setmainfont[Script=Thai]{TH Sarabun New}     % Thai alphabet
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale “th_TH”     % Thai alphabet
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}

% Add Package For Thai Page Number
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{thai}     % Thai alphabet
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Script=Thai]{TH Sarabun New:script=thai}     % Thai alphabet

%    %    % Set section number depth of ToC
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=green,
anchorcolor=cyan,
filecolor=red,
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfview=FitB
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Begin of Document
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

% Table of  Contents
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage

\mainmatter
% Chapter
\chapter{Chapter title = ชื่อบท}     %Thai alphabet
\section{Section title 1 = ส่วนที่ 1}     %Thai alphabet
การสังเคราะห์ข้อมูลน้ำฝนรายวันแบบ สโตแคสติคโดยใช้ลูกโซ่มาร์คอฟ ชนิดสองสถานะ และฟังก์ชันการแจกแจงแบบต่อเนื่อง\\
means\\
Stochastic Generation of Daily Rainfall Using Two-state Markov Chain and Continuous Distribution Functions\\
\cite{AP2011}

% Bibliography     %********************
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@article{AP2011,
  title={การสังเคราะห์ข้อมูลน้ำฝนรายวันแบบ สโตแคสติคโดยใช้ลูกโซ่มาร์คอฟ ชนิดสองสถานะ และฟังก์ชันการแจกแจงแบบต่อเนื่อง = Stochastic Generation of Daily Rainfall Using Two-state Markov Chain and Continuous Distribution Functions},
  author={Asasuppakit, Praopun},
  year={2011}
}
```

Figures showed Chapter 1 and Bibliography

Chapter page showed a fine page, but it still has some errors when running XeLatex.
Bibliography did not show anything.

[image: Chapter 1]

[image: Bib]

Comment: The problem with `fncychap` is that it uses the deprecated command `\rm`; add `oldfontcommands` to the options passed to the `memoir` class. This if you *really* want the Lenny chapter style, which is, in my opinion, very poorly designed. For the bibliography problem, without a minimal example it's impossible to say anything. However, BibTeX doesn't support alphabets different from Latin (and with many limitations for diacritics, too).

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment. I edited my code already. For fncychap, I tried to use a chapter style on my work. Lenny chapter style Is one of my attempts. I will find out how to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this a link which can fix my trouble relating to my question

2.
 \bibliography{bib} do not support Thai font.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1.23}
\title{ชื่อบทความ}
%% ใช้ร่วมกับ polyglossia เพื่อให้ได้วันที่ภาษาไทย
\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Script=Thai]{TH SarabunPSK}
\begin{document}
\fontspec[
ItalicFont={TH SarabunPSK Italic},
BoldFont={TH SarabunPSK Bold},
BoldItalicFont={TH SarabunPSK Bold Italic},
]{TH SarabunPSK}
\maketitle
\section*{ลองดูสิ}
ศึกษา \TeX\ อย่างละเอียด ให้ดู \cite{DK86} ถ้าต้องการเขียนสมการคณิตศาสตร์ให้ดู \cite{DK89}. แต่ถ้าเป็นของอาจารย์จักรี ลองอ้างอิงกับเล่มนี้ \cite{จักรีRC54} ดูนะครับ
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{testBibXeTex}
\end{document}
```

testBibXeTex.bib

```
@book{DK86, 
author = "D.E. Knuth",  
title = "The {\TeX}book",   
publisher = "Addison Wesley",   
year = 1986 
}   
@article{DK89,  
author = "D.E. Knuth",  
title = "Typesetting Concrete Mathematics", 
journal = "TUGboat",    
volume = 10,    
number = 1, 
pages = "31--36",   
month = apr,    
year = 1989 
}   
@book{จักรีRC54,    
author = "จักรี ติยะวงศ์สุวรรณ",    
title = "การออกแบบโครงสร้างคอนกรีตเสริมเหล็ก",  
publisher = "มปพ",  
year = 2554 
}
```

Credit: http://withxetex.blogspot.com/2011/11/bibtex-xelatex.html

จักรี ติยะวงศ์สุวรรณ

Mr.Chakkree Tiyawongsuwan

Comment: it's not so much that bibtex doesn't support "thai font"s, rather that it only supports 7-bit ascii by default.  the work-around makes it _support_ thai in utf-8, but it will have no chance of sorting entries -- you need to go to biber/biblatex for that, aiui.