# Bibliographies as a numbered sections in each chapter

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

Related to my previous question about **[Latex and Thai language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113359/latex-and-thai-language)**, now I have another one:

How to make bibliography as a section in each chapter **(at the last section of each chapter, such as section “1.10 References”)**

**Can we make it as a section in each chapter, such as 2.15 References for Chapter 2, and 15.18 References for Chapter 15?**

Now, no need to think of Thai language.
I translate name of books and etc. from Thai to Eng already.

Comment: see the biblatex package and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/per-chapter-bibliographies-in-biblatex for instance

Comment: It looks like all you want now is to have the bibliography heading be a numbered section heading, instead of an unnumbered chapter heading. This should be unrelated to the separation of the bibliography amongst chapters. You can try using `\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered]` (read in the `biblatex` manual, not tested).

Comment: I need to do something first and I will re-make the bibliography later. If I got something, I will be back to show the result.

Answer (score 3):

This is how this problem is solved automatically, i.e. without manually entering  `\begin{refsection}` and `\end{refsection}`. You just have to add `\printbibliography` at the end of each section.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{bib1,
   author = {Stuart Bennett},
   title = {Nicholas Minorsky and the automatic steering of ships},
   journal = {Control Systems Magazine, IEEE},
   volume = {4},
   number = {4},
   pages = {10-15},
   keywords = {History
Marine-vehicle control
Proportional control},
   year = {1984}
}
@article{bib2,
   author = {Nicholas Minorsky},
   title = {Directional Stability of Automatically Steered Bodies},
   journal = {Journal of the American Society for Naval Engineers},
   volume = {34},
   number = {2},
   pages = {280-309},
   year = {1922}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refsection=section,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Hi~\cite{bib1}.
\printbibliography      
\section{Main}
Hi~\cite{bib3}.
\printbibliography      
\end{document}
```

This code uses `natbib` and `bibunit` packages:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{bib1,
   author = {Stuart Bennett},
   title = {Nicholas Minorsky and the automatic steering of ships},
   journal = {Control Systems Magazine, IEEE},
   volume = {4},
   number = {4},
   pages = {10-15},
   keywords = {History
Marine-vehicle control
Proportional control},
   year = {1984}
}
@article{bib2,
   author = {Nicholas Minorsky},
   title = {Directional Stability of Automatically Steered Bodies},
   journal = {Journal of the American Society for Naval Engineers},
   volume = {34},
   number = {2},
   pages = {280-309},
   year = {1922}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}

\usepackage{bibunits}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
Hi~\cite{bib1}.
\putbib[references]
\end{bibunit}

\section{Main}
\begin{bibunit}[chicago]
Hi~\cite{bib2}.
\putbib[references]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

1. Instead of `chicago` or `plainnat`, you can use whatever style of your choice.
2. Delete the whole block from `\begin{filecontents*}...` to `\end{filecontents}`.
3. Change `\putbib[references]` and replace `references` with your own `.bib` file.
4. Instead of running `bibtex` on your main file, typeset your file with this order (of course, use whatever engine that is suitable for your choice of packages):

   - pdflatex mainfile
   - bibtex bu1
   - bibtex bu2
   - ...
   - pdflatex mainfile
   - pdflatex mainfile
5. I wasn't familiar with every language-specific details of your example, but this code must be applicable to your case.

Comment: This code made a lot of effect to my code structure. I am trying to re-write some code which will not make a lot of effect to my overall code.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any MWE, so I started from scratch using biblatex. If you have any special structure in mind, give an example of provide some details.

Comment: Please click this link (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113359/latex-and-thai-language) Thank you so much for your response and sorry about that.

Comment: I will edit my answer.

Comment: This code is so useful to make the reference at the end of each chapter. However, can we make it as a section in each chapter, such as 1.15 References for Chapter 1, and 15.18 References for Chapter 15?