# Using multiple bibliography files

Tags: bibliographies, memoir

Related to my previous question about [Latex and Thai language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113359/latex-and-thai-language), now I have another one:

How can I use multiple bibliography files in my document?

```
\bibliography{sample,ref,etc}
```

It did not work.
I have no idea what's wrong.

Now, no need to think of Thai language.
I translate name of books and etc. from Thai to Eng already.

Comment: 1.) Perhaps you could post a minimal example ?
2.) What do you mean by "coupled" ? 
3.) Do you use BibTeX or `biblatex` ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad. It is typo error. It should be "couple bibliography files". I use BibTex and plese take a look this link, Latex and Thai language,  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113359/latex-and-thai-language#comment263043_113359)

Comment: I tried to use 3 files of bibliography, namely sample,ref,etc. I used this command \bibliography{sample,ref,etc} to make it,  instead of \bibliography{bib} , but it did not work.

Comment: I rephrased the title and question a little bit, hope it's OK. If not, please undo my edit.

Comment: do you want to typeset 3 separate bibliographies or simply use the reference from all 3 in a single bibliography ?

Comment: I want to typeset 3 separate bibliographies.

Comment: Can you please add at least the error messages (if any) you've got? And which OS and editor you are using (or the command line)?

Comment: After finding out, I have just fixed it. Error came from my codes, order of them. Now, I can use 3 bibliography files.