# Thai bibliography apa7

Tags: bibliographies, polyglossia, apa-style

I try to make a bibliography in Thai with apa7 form. Is it possible without citation?

My attempt

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 0pt
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1.23}
\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}{Laksaman.otf}[%
ItalicFont={Laksaman-Italic.otf},%
BoldFont={Laksaman-Bold.otf},%
BoldItalicFont={Laksaman-BoldItalic.otf},%
Script=Thai,%
Scale=MatchLowercase,%
WordSpace=1.25,%
Mapping=tex-text,%
]

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm using Texstudio version 4.2.3.

Comment: Welcome! Normally, when one has no citation, one has to add `\nocite{*}` in the preamble to obtain the bibliography.

Comment: I think the issue is not with `\nocite{*}`. The doc compiles with errors on Overleaf and produces PDF with bibliography. See my answer on what the error is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document compiles with errors for me on Overleaf when using XeLaTeX. The resulting PDF does show the bibliography. The error complains that there is no `.lbx` file for Thai language. Seems there isn't one: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx

See this if you want to use unsupported language:
[What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200932/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-configure-biblatex-for-use-with-an-unsupport)

Comment: That said, I’m not entirely sure that LaTeX can properly typeset Thai since the line breaking rules require a word dictionary because Thai script is written without spaces between words but line breaks can only happen at word boundaries. Plus, for justified text, if there is no punctuation (which has spaces after it which can be stretched), it will likely be necessary to uniformly adjust the inter-character spacing.

Comment: Although apparently some people have limited success using LaTeX for Thai: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113359/latex-and-thai-language

Comment: @DonHosek agreed. Typesetting with LaTeX of non-Latin/Cyrillic languages is a toll order.